# Let $G=D_8\times\mathbb{Z_6}$ and $N=D_8\times\{0\}$. Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group, dihedral-groups

> Let $G=D_8\times\mathbb{Z_6}$ and $N=D_8\times\{0\}$. Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

**My attempt:**

I proved that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Then we can define

$$G/N = \{gN \mid g\in G\}.$$

Let $x\in G/N$ then $x=g\cdot n$ where $g\in G$ and $n\in N$. Moreover: $g\in G$, then $g=(a,b)$ where $a\in D_8$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}_6$.

If $n \in N$ then $n=(c,0)$ where $c$ in $D_8$ and $0\in \{0\}$.

This implies: $x=(a\cdot c, b \oplus0) = (a\cdot c,b)$

Now, we can define the function $f: G/N \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ such that $f((a\cdot c,b))=b$.

This function is clearly  bijective and

$$f((a\cdot c,b))f((a'\cdot c',b'))=bb' = f((a\cdot c,bb'))$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: First of all, $x \in G/N \implies x=gN$ for some $g \in G$, not $x \in G/N \implies x=gn$ for some $g \in G$ and $n \in N$.

Comment: This holds in general, not only for $D_8\times C_6$. In a direct product $G\times H$, $G\times 1$ is always a normal subgroup with $(G\times H)/(G\times 1)\cong H$. See the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a map

$$\begin{align}
f: G& \to \Bbb Z_6, \\
 (a,b) &\mapsto b.
\end{align}$$

Clearly $f$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Observe that $N$ is the kernel of this homomorphism.

By the first isomorphism theorem, $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)